# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_password() or wp_mail()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I would like to generate a unique password hash and try to use the following wordpress function:

```
$activation_token = wp_generate_password();
update_user_meta($user_id, 'activation_token', $activation_token);
```

Unfortunately, it not work because `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_password()`

Is this function deprecated? I cannot find anything else in WordPress documentation.

**Edit:** I try the code in my wordpress theme and in works! So the problem is, i cannot call any wordpress core functions? I have the same problem with `wp_mail()`

I updated the wordpress installation, use the default Twenty theme and deactivated all other plugins but i have still the same probelm! wp_ functions not work in plugin, why?

Comment: Which file in your plugin are you trying to call this function from?

Comment: Make sure that your code is hooked into WordPress at the right time. For instance, if you're writing a plugin, you should use hooks like init or plugins_loaded to ensure WordPress functions are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call many parts of the WordPress system until it's loaded. Most stuff in plugins needs to be invoked from within the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) action handler, or some other filter or action handler.

Try something like this.

```php
<?php
namespace Hareth;

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  exit;
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'Hareth\init', 'init' ) );

function init() {
  $activation_token = wp_generate_password();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/

> Uses wp_rand() to create passwords with far less predictability than
> similar native PHP functions like rand() or mt_rand().

Comment: Not sure what this solves - it just seems to be something from the manual page explaining how it works.